# How to translate Datepicker in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to use the component `DatePicker` in Angular, to receive a date with the possibility to be translate in according to the Browser translate/locale. How Can I do?

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, when you got the date from datepicket, you could get browser locale in this way:

```
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
```

then you could use `moment` to visualize date in current locale like this. See this small example:

```js
let yourdatefromdatepicker = moment();
// get locale from browser
var locale = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
//print current locale
console.log(moment.locale(locale));
// yourdatefromdatepicker date in current locale
console.log(yourdatefromdatepicker.locale(locale))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I want to show also the month in the local language. I'm not sure how to set the bowser language.

Comment: Ciao, you have a particular format to show? I can suggest some formats but maybe you want a particular one. For example to show month in locale you could use `yourdatefromdatepicker.locale(locale).format('LLLL')` but also `yourdatefromdatepicker.locale(locale).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a default language for all material components in your Angular application you can do the following:

In your app module you should import the MAT_DATE_LOCALE and LOCALE_ID, the registration function and the locale you want to add (in my case Dutch):

```
import { MatNativeDateModule, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeNl from '@angular/common/locales/nl';
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
```

Then you must register the locale:

```
registerLocaleData(localeNl);
```

Finally you must provide the new locale:

```
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'nl-NL' },
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'nl-NL' }
  ]
```

This will make all your material components use the language that you set here.
For more information about which languages are supported by Angular refer to [this link](https://angular.io/guide/i18n).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The language can be detected via browser or from a user field; how Can I procide?

Comment: Well do you want to get the language based on the browser or is it ok if the user chooses a language in the application from a dropdown? If you dont mind the user choosing his/her prefered language I can add some code in my answer to show you how to do that.

Comment: As now it would be to use the browser’s language! Once I got the point, I hope I’ll be able to perform also the last task! I just to programatically set it!

Comment: Ok then I advise you to look into this blog: https://medium.com/@kristinahertmann/multi-language-date-formats-with-angular-material-b8598415d117

It has quite the nice explanation and what you need from there is the changing of the date adapter so that the material datepicker can actully pick up the changes. If you have trouble implementing it write here and I will try to put it in a plunker.

Comment: Thank you! It seems really complicated this approach! I mean I should set the adapter in each component?

Comment: No the adapter stays in your app.module.ts where you put it as provider and afterwards you can swap it on demand. I think this should be easiest for you.